# C# ExcelLibrary and changing the font/decoration of cells

Tags: c#, excel

Using [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/), how can I:

- Change cell font to bold/italic
- Merge cells
- Create a border around cells

I've searched through the, rather limited, documentation and haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Are there any other Excel libraries which combine the ease of ExcelLibrary with a bit more functionality? (Different question I know).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), at least it's documentation is quite nice.

Comment: I've just had a look and, indeed, it is documented better than ExcelLibrary. Also, creating worksheets and saving them seems just as easy. Thank you.

Comment: -1 because it doesn't answer the question in re: to ExcelLibrary.